# Python ElementTree won't update new file after parsing

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

Using `ElementTree` to parse attribute's value in an **XML** and writing a new **XML** file. It will console the new updated value and write a new file. But won't update any changes in the new file. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. Here is **XML** & **Python** code:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
-->
    <req action="get" msg="1" rank="1" rnklst="1" runuf="0" status="1" subtype="list" type="60" univ="IL" version="fhf.12.000.00" lang="ENU" chunklimit="1000" Times="1">
        <flds>
            <f i="bond(long) hff"  aggregationtype="WeightedAverage" end="2016-02-29" freq="m" sid="fgg" start="2016-02-29"/>
            <f i="bond(short) ggg"  aggregationtype="WeightedAverage" end="2016-02-29" freq="m" sid="fhf" start="2016-02-29"/>
        </flds>
    <dat>
        <r i="hello" CalculationType="3" Calculate="1" />
    </dat>
</req>
```

**Python**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

with open('test.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter('r'):
    port_id = node.attrib.get('i')
    new_port_id = port_id.replace(port_id, "new")
    print node

tree.write('./new_test.xml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the attribute `i`, and assign it to `port_id`, you just have a regular Python string. Calling replace on it is just the Python string `.replace()` method.

You want to use the [`.set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set) method of the etree node:

```
for node in tree.iter('r'):
    node.set('i', "new")
    print node
```